# Bigquery Unloading Large Data to a Single GZIP File

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the BigQuery console and was planning to extract a table and put the results into Google Cloud Storage as a GZIP file but encountered an error asking to wilcard the filename as based on Google docs, it's like a limitation for large volume of data and extract needs to be splitted.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#console

By any chance is there a workaround so I could have a single compressed file loaded to Google Cloud Storage instead of multiple files? I was using Redshift previously and this wasn't an issue.

Comment: I think having a single file isn't feasible. According to the documentation any export greater than 1 GB needs to be split using a wildcard https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data .

What is your use case exactly? Perhaps can help based on how exactly you plan to use the single file export. My usual recommendation is to limit columns and rows to a time range to be able to fit into the 1 GB limit

Comment: the file will be shared to a third party group. they would need to update their job/scripts then to process multiple files unless they are BQ or Redshift which can load files using wildcards.

Comment: How frequently do they do this? can they pull it more frequently say hourly so that you get much smaller csv(gzip) files? Most filesystems have a maximum file size and csv files > 2 GB are generally not usable interactively. You should consider BQ authorized views(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views) if reducing file size isn't an option